# HTML / CSS Page break not working

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I have this page with multiple records I want to print.

The problem is that I get a blank page at the end.

My CSS:

```
.break { 
    page-break-after: always; 
    }
```

My html/php:

```
...
</table>
  <p class="break">&nbsp;</p>
    <?php } while ($row_RSacessorios = mysql_fetch_assoc($RSacessorios)); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($RSacessorios);
mysql_free_result($RSfases);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, because you are emitting a page break after, always. Not sure what the problem is, really. It does exactly what you asked. If you don't want that, ask for something else, for instance by removing the `class="break"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. I just remove the class "break" on the last record.

```
if ($count < $total_rec) {
  <p class="break">&nbsp;</p>
}
```